# accessing subclass variable from parent class

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a declaration like this

```
TransactionItemDto itemDto = getTransactionItemMessage().getTransactionItemDto();
```

then I have the following piece of code:

```
if (itemDto instanceof ChangeTransactionItemDto) {
            inputItem.setSiteCode(itemDto.getSiteCode()));
            inputItem.setBinLocation(itemDto.getBinLocation()));

        }
```

Now, I have variable '`department`' which belongs to `ChangeTransactionItemDto` only. But I am not able to do this currently inside the if block above: `inputItem.setDepartment(itemDto.getDepartment()));`

Thats because itemDto is declared of type `TransactionItemDto`  and not `ChangeTransactionItemDto`.

I can check the value during the debug process if I do `itemDto.getDepartment()` since internally its of the subclass type. but the statement gives error. 
How do I set the department belonging to the subclass - `ChangeTransactionItemDto` on the `inputItem`?

Comment: I guess One way is to do an explicit cast: ChangeTransactionItemDto cItemDto = (ChangeTransactionItemDto)itemDto; inside the if block.

Comment: Your data model needs to be fixed; if you need to be able to access `department`, you need to be working with a variable whose type includes it. This is like trying to access the ZIP code on an `Address` even if you don't know whether the `Address` is a `UnitedStatesAddress`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have verified if `itemDto` is of instance `ChangeTransactionItemDto`, you can always call `inputItem.setDepartment(((ChangeTransactionItemDto)itemDto).getDepartment())`

Answer (score 0):

It is a design smell if super class needs access to subclass-specific fields.

One work around is to pull the getter/setter up into the super class with a "do nothing" implementation, then those sub classes that use it override it with a "do something" implementation.

This way there is no class in the class hierarchy that needs special treatment - they can *all* be treated the same way.